# Can I combine 2 UIImages?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm having a hard time fixing my code. How can I add and combine 2 UIImages without using the `addSubview` method? Is there any possible solution to combining 2 UIImages?.this is my code

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(piece1.frame, piece2.frame))
    { 
        if (piece1.center.x < piece2.center.x) 
        { 
            NSLog(@"ok"); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do a search here - there are many questions + answers on this.

Comment: >what will i add here if i want to combined the 2 uiimages?-


(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(piece1.frame, piece2.frame)){
        if (piece1.center.x < piece2.center.x) {
            NSLog(@"ok");
          

   
    }}
}

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` is your friend, assuming you are trying to composite two `UIImage` into a new one.

Comment: @DaDODU: you need to do some research.

Comment: @DaDODU don't post code in comments. Instead, edit your original post.

Comment: can you help me guys?. I'm just a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this. (I haven't check the code, beware). And there is a variety of blendMode available.

```
CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight));

[piece1 drawInRect: drawRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
[piece2 drawInRect: drawRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeScreen alpha:1];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```